# PHP Imap Certificate failure

Tags: php, imap

I was pulling my inboxes using [php-imap/php-imap](https://packagist.org/packages/php-imap/php-imap) library and inboxes managed by CPanel. All in sudden script stopped with following error.

```
Connection error: Certificate failure for imap.domain.com: 
Server name does not match certificate: 
/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=<amazon.domain.com>
```

in /.../vendor/php-imap/php-imap/src/PhpImap/Mailbox.php

here is the imap path I am using:
    `{imap.domain.com:143/imap/tls}INBOX`

I also tried `{imap.domain.com:143/novalidate-cert/imap/tls}INBOX` but all in vain.

**What change could have have stopped it?**
**How to fix it and avoid such failure in future?**

Comment: Get imap.domain.com added to the certificate, or connect to amazon.domain.com.

Comment: Also, port 143 is not normally used for secure IMAP.  Are you sure that's what you're using?

Answer (score 1):

IMAP port is 993..143 for POP..Try it..

```
{imap.domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
```